# ModalController not working in Ionic cordova

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am connecting to an API and displaying the information for each result of that API onto a card. The next thing I am trying to add is a way for a user to click on that card and display additional information for the card on a new page. I am currently trying to using modalCtrl, navParams to do so but everything I am trying just results in an error saying "(uncaught) in promise: TypeErorr, Cannot read property 'create' of undefined. (I understand the error but do not know a method to get around it)
All help is appreciated! Code is below (let me know if you need anything else):

dining.page.ts

```
import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RestaurantsService } from '../services/restaurants.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SelectedCardPage } from '../selected-card/selected-card.page';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dining',
  templateUrl: './dining.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dining.page.scss'],
})
export class DiningPage implements OnInit {
  cards = {}

  constructor( private restaurantsService: RestaurantsService ) { };

  ngOnInit() {}

  async onSelected(card) {
      const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
        component: SelectedCardPage,
        componentProps: { value: cards}
      });
      return await modal.present();
  }
```

dining.page.html

```
  <ion-card (click)="onSelected(card)" class="welcome-card" *ngFor="let item of restaurantsService.restaurants">
    <img class='image' src='{{ item.restaurant.featured_image }}' alt='' />
    <ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-title class='text'>{{ item.restaurant.name }}</ion-card-title>
      <ion-card-subtitle class='text'>{{ item.restaurant.phone_numbers }}</ion-card-subtitle>
      <ion-card-subtitle class='text'>{{ item.restaurant.location.address }}</ion-card-subtitle>
    </ion-card-header>
  </ion-card>
```

selected-card.page.html

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-title>{{ item.restaurant.name }}</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>
  <ion-card (click)="dismiss()">
    {{ value }}
  </ion-card>
</ion-content>
```

selected.card.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { RestaurantsService } from '../services/restaurants.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-selected-card',
  templateUrl: './selected-card.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./selected-card.page.scss'],
})
export class SelectedCardPage implements OnInit {
  value: string;
  constructor(private modalCtrl: ModalController,
              private navParams: NavParams) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.value = this.navParams.get('value');
  }

  dismiss() {
    this.modalCtrl.dismiss();
  }

}
```

app.module.ts (just in case)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouteReuseStrategy } from '@angular/router';

import { IonicModule, IonicRouteStrategy } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { SelectedCardPageModule } from './selected-card/selected-card.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    SelectedCardPageModule
  ],
```

Comment: this.modalCtrl - you have not inject dependency in contructor of diningpaga.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare  modalCtrl in constructor as well

```
    import { ModalController } from '@ionic/angular';
    import { RestaurantsService } from '../services/restaurants.service';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { SelectedCardPage } from '../selected-card/selected-card.page';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dining',
      templateUrl: './dining.page.html',
      styleUrls: ['./dining.page.scss'],
    })
    export class DiningPage implements OnInit {
      cards = {}

      constructor( 
    private restaurantsService: RestaurantsService , 
    private modalCtrl :ModalController ) { };

      ngOnInit() {}

      async onSelected(card) {
          const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
            component: SelectedCardPage,
            componentProps: { value: cards}
          });
          return await modal.present();
      }
```